# "Nice" bases for finite dimensional semisimple Hopf algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a finite dimensional semisimple Hopf algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Can one choose a basis $\{h_1, \dots, h_n \}$ of $H$, where $h_1 = 1$, such that if we write 
$$
\Delta(h_i) = \sum_{1 \leq j,k \leq n} \alpha_{ijk} h_j \otimes h_k
$$
for some $\alpha_{ijk} \in \mathbb{C}$, then $\alpha_{ij1} = 0$ for all $i,j$, except $i=1$ (since obviously $\Delta(1) = 1 \otimes 1$)? That is, if we write $\Delta(h_i)$ as the sum of $n$ tensors where the second tensorand is a basis vector, is $h_1$ the only basis vector with a nonzero summand of the form $- \otimes 1$?

If $H = \mathbb{C}G$ is a group algebra, then the basis consisting of grouplike elements obviously has this property. If $G = \mathbb{Z}_p$ is cyclic of order $p$, then $(\mathbb{C} \mathbb{Z}_p)^*$ has this property (and I think this is true for any finite abelian group). Many examples I know of have this property (e.g. the Kac-Palyutkin Hopf algebra). However, I can't tell if this is true for $(\mathbb{C} S_3)^*$, for example.

In general, if we let $G(H)$ denote the set of grouplikes, then it might be sensible to consider a basis consisting of unions of cosets of $G(H)$. However, I haven't been able to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a basis for $H$ of the sort you are looking for, let $V$ be the linear span of $h_2, \dots, h_n$. Then $V \cap \mathbb C1 = 0$ and $\Delta(V) \subset V \otimes V$. Conversely, given such a $V$, any basis for $V$, together with 1, will do what you ask.

Carefully dualizing, we are asking if the dual Hopf algebra $H^*$ must have a 1-dimensional two sided ideal that is not contained in the kernel of the dual of the unit $\eta^*: H^* \rightarrow \mathbb C$.

Let try this out when $H$ is the dual of a group algebra, so $H^* = \mathbb C G$. Is there such a 1-dimensional ideal?  Yes: let $\bar G = \sum_{g \in G}g \in H^* = \mathbb C G$.  The span of this element is a one dimensional ideal, and the element has augmentation $|G|$, not 0.

Comment: Note that *any* finite dimensional Hopf algebra over a field has the space of left integrals as two-sided 1-dimensional ideal. So, if your criterium is true, this would answer the question positively.

Comment: @tj_ I made my answer more definitive, and slightly different.  One is left with:  does every finite dimensional Hopf algebra over a field have a one dimensional two sided ideal not in the kernel of the augmentation?

Comment: I believe I worked this out, although using a different method. Let $T \in H^*$ be an integral for $H$, and choose a basis $\{ h_1, \dots, h_n \}$ for $H$, where $h_1 = 1$ (possible since $H$ is semisimple) and $T(h_i) = 0$ for $i \neq 1$ (which can be achieved by subtracting a scalar multiple of $1$ from each basis element, if necessary). Then, writing $\Delta(h_i)$ as in my question and calculating $\delta_{h_i} * T$ using the fact that $T$ is an integral, you find that this basis has the desired properties.

Comment: @Nicholas Kuhn: Cute. I don't know the answer in general, but under the assumption of the OP's question, $H$ is semisimple, which is equivalent to $\epsilon(L)\neq 0$ where $\epsilon$ is the augmentation and $L$ the 1-dim. space of left integrals. So $L$ works.